# ActionBar never works on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I am developing an app, and I have created a NavigationDrawerActivity as my main activity on Eclipse. But when I run the application I awalys get the `ClassNotFoundException`. I've created the NavigatorDrawerActivity by Eclipse New Project Wizard. I remember that I can never use the extends `ActionBarAcitivity` on any apps developed in Eclipse. Why can't I create `Activity extends ActionBarAcitivity` on Eclipse? Did someone had this problem too?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So, I am also using Android Studio. But I am having another prblem. Take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238047/asynctask-listview-json-android-studio-error), please.

Comment: @henriqueromao It is possible to create activity which `extends ActionBarActivity` in Eclipse. Refer my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29252642/4290431

Comment: You need to add `AppCompat v7` in your eclipse project, in order to use `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: @Pooja How do I do that? Bucause I aalready have appCompat 7 in my project, but I might have done something wrong. How do u add the lib?

Comment: Right click on your project. Select configure build path. Add `AppCompat v7` there. @henriqueromao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started using Android Studio. Solved the issues.